# NCURSES: creating a title bar without loops

Tags: c++, c, ncurses

I wanted to create a program where I can stop, start and monitor processes and their outputs, notifications, errors, etc. Probably has been done but I haven't found it.

This my first ncurses program and I'm having a styling issue. I'm reading in an XML file which contains all the initial layout information. This breaks up the terminal into a few sections. Each section I wanted to have a title bar. This would simply be A_REVERSE, or a specified fg/bg color pair.

I hadn't discovered the `wattr_on() wattr_off()` functions til a minute ago. That's a step in the right direction. But I make a call to `wborder()` and I'm getting characters where I want none. Specifically:

`wborder(pwin, '\0', '\0', ' ', '\0', ' ', ' ', '\0', '\0');`

I wanted the `NULL`s to be no character, not the default. I was trying to do this without loops. Is it possible?

**Answer**

```
mvwhline(pwin,0,0,' ',xmax);
wprintw(pwin,"%s",sztitle);
mvwchgat(pwin,0,0,-1,A_REVERSE,0,0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window borders are window borders, not a headline. If you only want that, it's probably best to just use `mvwchgat()` to make the headline stand out.

Comment: My perspective came from CSS... namely the `border` properties. Like `border-top`. Thank you. That worked great. More googling revealed `hline()` :D I know it was a simple question, my attention is in like a dozen directions. This was a big help, thanks again.